# how to Read a row starting with a specific integer in text file python?

Tags: python, row, text-files, extract

My problem is that I need to read and print a specific line starting with a specific integer(input by user) from text file.

This is my text file information:

1   ,   'USA'    ,   7244184    ,   53629       ,   208440  ,  895

2   ,   'Mexico'  , 715457  ,   5408        ,   75439   ,    490

3   ,   'Ireland'  ,    33995   ,   319     ,       1797  ,     3

4   ,   'India'   , 5901571 ,   85468       ,   93410  ,    1093

5   ,   'Turkey'    , 311455    ,   7858    ,       7858  ,     73

8    ,   'Qatar' ,  124650  ,    220       ,      212   ,   2

example:

if user entered code = 8

I need the program to print [8,Qatar,124650,220,212,2]

what should I do?

Comment: It depends on how you have it structured. Do you have this text file already opened and processed, or do you intend to open and process it every time a user enters a code?

Comment: @K.Cl I have this file already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
n = int(input())

with open('./file.txt') as f:

    content = f.read().splitlines()

    for line in content:

        if int(line[0]) == n:
            elements = line.split(',') # a list of individual elements
```

Comment: but how to extract each element from the output list?

Comment: What is it you want to do? I thought you wanted the program to just print the output.

Comment: I need to get each element from the choosen row

Comment: example: if the user entered 8 i need to get 8 alone Qatar alone and so on

Comment: See my update. `elements` is a list of the individual components of the line. Depending on what you want to do, you just index the list for that specific element.

Answer (score 1):

According to seeing the structure file it looks like csv it is better you could use pandas and follow the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)
#you can read txt file also and set seperator like this pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
userinput=input()
print(df.loc[df[0] == int(userinput)])
```

Let me know if you have any Questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Your file is a csv (comma-separated values), for that there is a possibility to read it as a dataframe (see pandas).

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("your_file.txt", names=["Country", "column_2", "column_3", "column_4", "column_5"], index_col=0)
```

[result of reading the csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsvnP.png)

```
user_input = int(input())
result = dataframe.iloc[user_input]
print(result)
```

You will have in return an Object with the values of each column.

```
print(result.Country)
```

ps : You have to install the library pandas, if you have pip just type : `pip install pandas`. If you don't have it, install pip first you will need it, just google how to install pip.